# Vaadin DateTimePicker becomes null if only one field (date or time field) is entered

Tags: java, vaadin, datetimepicker

I have vaadin DateTimePicker component and I am using it to filter some datas. If users entered only one of date or time field, DateTimePicker component's value becomes null. I want to get date and time field seperately. Actually, I need to set time field to default value such as 12:00AM, If user entered only date field. However I couldnt find which field is null and the value of field which is not null.

I've tried to assign it's value to LocalDateTime parameter but whenever I use getValue() method for DateTimePicker which has one null field, the value returns as null.

```
private DateTimePicker start = new DateTimePicker();
        private boolean isTimeNull(){
            LocalDateTime dateTime = start.getValue();
        }
```

Comment: If you need separate fields, you can use DatePicker and TimePicker standalone.

Comment: I know that, however, using separate components will be confusing when we try to bind components into the pre-made binder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value for the other field (usually Time) is a missing feature in the component. But you can workaround that with JavaScript.

https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/668

Here is example how to pad time with zero hours if missing.

```
  DateTimePicker picker = new DateTimePicker();
 
  picker.getElement().executeJs("this.getElementsByTagName(\"vaadin-date-time-picker-date-picker\")[0].addEventListener('change', function(){this.getElementsByTagName(\"vaadin-date-time-picker-time-picker\")[0].value='00:00';}.bind(this));");
  picker.addValueChangeListener(event -> {      
      Notification.show(event.getValue().toString());
  });
  add(picker);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tatu, it helped me a lot. I wonder will this problem or bug be solved in future by vaadin team?

Comment: Well, there is a ticket for it, so it might. You can increase the probability of that happening by adding a thumbs-up reaction to the (main comment of the) ticket.

Comment: Thank you I've just given a thumbs-up reaction but I am not sure whether or not the ticket is going to be solved because its status has not been changed for 4 years.

Comment: gotta love Vaadin's fight for simplicity! Especially when upgrading causes new changes. As of Vaadin 24, Alejandro's answer of May 25, 2023 works and Tatu's became deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I had that code of previous answer running for Vaadin 14, but after migrating to Vaadin 24 I had to change the names of the tags. It was "vaadin-date-time-picker-date-picker" for the date, and "vaadin-date-time-picker-time-picker" for the time. Now is "vaadin-date-picker" and "vaadin-time-picker".

```java
DateTimePicker picker = new DateTimePicker();

picker.getElement().executeJs(
        "this.getElementsByTagName(\"vaadin-date-picker\")[0].addEventListener('change', function(){" +
                "if (!this.getElementsByTagName(\"vaadin-time-picker\")[0].value) this.getElementsByTagName(\"vaadin-time-picker\")[0].value='00:00';" +
        "}.bind(this));"
);
        
picker.addValueChangeListener(event -> Notification.show(event.getValue().toString()));
add(picker);
```